# Java Deserialization Error

Tags: java, serialization

So for some reason stack overflow won't let me post more than 2 links so here is a link containing links: http://pastebin.com/FERUSH2P

Hello, so I have no idea why but I am getting ClassNotFoundException when 
trying to deserialize a .bin file.  I am serializing in one program and deserializing in another.  The serialversion IDs are the same.  Here is class in the first program: (Link 1) and the second program: (Link 2) Here is seriazation code (in second program): (Link 3) And here is deserialization code (in first program): (Link 4) And finally here is the error: (Link 5)

I would really appreciate any help!  Thanks!

EDIT: By the way, getCause() returns null

EDIT: I fixed it by moving the classes now are in packages with the same name.  Thanks!

Comment: No links. Post the code and the stacks trace here. You really have no idea why you get a ClassNotFoundException?

Comment: @DerekLesho - *"There are links!"* - Yes! We know!!!  That is why you are getting downvotes, and votes to close.  Don't post links to pastebin, or similar sites.  Just don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct (except for a minor remark - it's better to put your "stream.close()" in "finally" clauses).
The error clearly indicates that the reading side doesn't have class "AnimatedModelData" on its classpath. Your can verify it by calling Class.forName("core.ModelData.AnimatedModelData") on the reading side, even without reading the stream. The standard solution is to compile such model classes once, optionally package them as a jar, then adding them to the classpath of both sides - reader and writer.